# convert String to TIMESTAMP fo inserting time in table?

Tags: java, jdbc

I created a table :

`create table Appointment(
App_ID number primary key,
Doctor_ID number,
Patient_ID number,
App_Date Date,
App_Time TIMESTAMP,
App_Charges number);`

i know how to convert String to java.sql.Date.
But for time i'm doing

```
 String s1=time.getSelelctedItem().toString();//specifying time from a combo box
```

and then

```
  st.setString(5,s1);
```

Please tell me the changes i need to make..
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a `java.util.Date` in the middle:

```
// Specifying time from a combo box
String s1 = time.getSelelctedItem().toString();

// Convert String to Date according to the format
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
Date date = df.parse(s1);

// Convert Date to Timestamp
Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(date.getTime());

// Set it:
st.setTimestamp(5, ts);
```

Comment: i'm getting parseexception:unparsable date "10:00"
combo box contains time in the form : "10:00" , "10:15","09:10"

Comment: You need to provide the appropriate format - I edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

check the below code :

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
String dateInString = "29/03/2014";

try {

    Date date = formatter.parse(dateInString);
    java.sql.Timestamp timest = new java.sql.Timestamp(date.getTime()); 
    System.out.println(timest.getDate());

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

so timest is the timestamp got from date which is parsed from datestring "29/03/2014" using SimpleDateFormat.